# Most efficient way to generate possible plugboard settings for the enigma with python

Tags: python, list, generator

I'm looking at breaking the enigma cipher with python, and need to generate plugboard combinations - what I need is a function which takes a `length` parameter and returns a generator object of all possible combinations as a list.

Example code:

```py
for comb in func(2):
   print(comb)
```

```py
# Example output
['AB', 'CD']
['CD', 'EF']
...
```

Does anyone know of a library that provides such a generator, or how to go about making one?

EDIT: more detail about enigma

Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine#Plugboard) for detail about the design of the plugboard

Also, the output format of the generator must be concatanable to this format *without* running the whole generator:

`'AB FO ZP GI HY KS JW MQ XE ...'` the number of pairs would be the `length` parameter in the function.

Comment: Could you [edit] and add a description of the algorithm, for those of us who aren't familiar with Enigma? Asking cause the given outputs aren't simple combinations.

Comment: The Wikipedia page doesn't mention the algorithm

Comment: @wjandrea algorithm?

Comment: yeah, how are plugboard settings generated? Or what pattern do they follow?

Comment: They weren't during the war. The plugboard was a simple, physical, substitution cipher that added to enigma's security. The format I need is described above; eg `'AB FO ZP GI HY KS JW MQ XE ...'` means that `A` maps to `B` and vice versa, `F` to `O`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations('abcd', 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> [''.join(comb) for comb in combinations('abcd', 2)]
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd']
```

Comment: It would kinda work, but to make it work you would need much more (extra) code, and to run the entire generator object as a list, which wouldn't work for me seeing as I will be running the generator with an output of aproximately 9 trillion items - this would cause a memory error in most PC's

Answer (score 0):

Is this something close to what you're after?  Let me know and I can revise.

The `plugboard()` function returns (`yield`) a `generator` object which can be accessed either by an iterable loop, or by calling the `next()` function.

```
from itertools import product

def plugboard(chars, length):
    for comb in product(chars, repeat=length):
        yield ''.join(comb)
```

#### A call such as this will create `combs` as a `generator` object:

```
combs = plugboard('abcde', 2)
type(combs)

>>> generator
```

#### To access the values you can use either:

```
next(combs)
>>> 'aa'
```

#### Or:

```
for i in combs: print(i)

ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bb
bc
...
```

Comment: I shall try this function out.